# MySQL all rows that only match a field value

Tags: mysql

*EDITED*

I need to execute a query that only brings me the **user_id** who have all of his phones **confirmed = 2**, not just one or two, must be all of them.

My table looks like this:

```
 id      user_id    phone        confirmed
 ------- --------   -----------  ---
 1       1          3051234561   1
 1       1          3051234562   0
 1       1          3051234563   2
 1       2          3051234564   2
 1       2          3051234565   2
 1       2          3051234566   2
 1       3          3051234567   0
 1       3          3051234568   1
 1       4          3051234569   1
```

**In this case must return user_id 2**

I was trying to do it with GROUP HAVING but Iam not getting the result I need. Example:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
    phones
GROUP BY 
    user_id
HAVING 
    MAX(confirmed) = 2
```

Comment: `SELECT
distinct user_id
FROM
    phones
GROUP BY 
    user_id
HAVING 
    sum(confirmed) = 0 `

Comment: If you name a column `id`, it's probably a good idea (for human readability) to have unique values in there, not all `1`s.

Comment: It have it, I only forgot to modify it while typing it!

Comment: Strik3r sorry i had an error on the question, I edited it already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
 user_id
FROM
  phones
GROUP BY 
  user_id
HAVING 
  COUNT(IF(confirmed = 2, 1, NULL)) = COUNT(*)
```

Output:

```
+---------+
| user_id |
+---------+
|       2 |
+---------+
```

Comment: How about confirmed = 0 and confirmed = 2 but NOT confirmed = 1

Comment: I did HAVING COUNT(IF(b.confirmed != 1, 1, NULL)) = COUNT(*) but that includes all that have all phones confirmed = 2, but what i need now is that have confirmed = 0 BUT doesnt have confirmed = 1

Comment: Try this one - COUNT(IF(confirmed = 0 OR confirmed = 2, 1, NULL)) = COUNT(*)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT distinct user_id FROM phones GROUP BY user_id HAVING sum(confirmed) = 2 * count(confirmed)
```

this will give all user_id who haven't any confirmed phone

Comment: Read the answer again i modify it, i need all that have all their phones confirmed = 2

Answer (score 0):

You need a `WHERE` condition before your `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following one....

```
   "SELECT * FROM phones WHERE confirmed='0' GROUP BY user_id"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
SELECT *
FROM phones
Where confirmed= 0
GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this

```
SELECT user_id FROM phones WHERE confirmed=0 GROUP BY user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT distinct user_id FROM phones GROUP BY user_id HAVING sum(confirmed) = 0

You wrote:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
    phones
GROUP BY 
    user_id
HAVING 
    MAX(confirmed) = 2
```

Now you need all the confirmed to be 0, getting their sum must be zero, and you want not all attributes but user_id:

```
SELECT
    distinct(user_id)
FROM
    phones
GROUP BY 
    user_id
HAVING 
    SUM(confirmed) = 0
```